# Calculating how many times sentence words are repeating in the file

Tags: python, list, dictionary, file-handling

I want to check how  many times a word is repeating in the file. I have seen other codes on finding words in file but they won't solve my problem.From this I mean if I want to find "Python is my favourite language"The program will split the text will tell how many times it has repeated in the file.

```
def search_tand_export():
        file = open("mine.txt")
        #targetlist = list()
        #targetList = [line.rstrip() for line in open("mine.txt")]
        contentlist = file.read().split(" ")
        string=input("search box").split(" ")
        print(string)
        fre={}
        outputfile=open("outputfile.txt",'w')
        for word in contentlist:
            print(word)
            for i in string:
               # print(i)
                if i == word:
                    print(f"'{string}' is in text file ")
                    outputfile.write(word)
                    print(word)
    
                    spl=tuple(string.split())
                    for j in range(0,len(contentist)):
    
            
                        if spl in contentlist:
                            fre[spl]+=1 
                        else:
                            fre[spl]=1   
                        sor_list=sorted(fre.items(),key =lambda x:x[1])
                        for x,y in sor_list:
                            print(f"Word\tFrequency")
                            print(f"{x}\t{y}")
            else:
                continue
                
        print(f"The word or collection of word is not present")
    search_tand_export()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you're trying to do.
But I suppose you are trying to find how many times every word from a given sentence is repeated in the file.

If this is the case, you can try something like this:

```
sentence = "Python is my favorite programming language"
words = sentence.split()

with open("file.txt") as fp:
    file_data = fp.read()

for word in words:
    print(f"{file_data.count(word)} occurence(s) of '{word}' found")
```

Note that the code above is case-sensitive (that is, "Python" and "python" are different words). To make it case-insensitive, you can bring `file_data` and every word during comparison to lowercase using `str.lower()`.

```
sentence = "Python is my favorite programming language"
words = sentence.split()

with open("file.txt") as fp:
    file_data = fp.read().lower()

for word in words:
    print(f"{file_data.count(word.lower())} occurence(s) of '{word}' found")
```

---

A couple of things to note:

1. You are opening a file and even don't close it finally (although you should). It's better to use `with open(...) as ...` (context-manager), so the file is closed automatically.
2. Python strings (as well as lists, tuples etc.) have `.count(what)` method. It returns how many occurences of `what` are found in the object.
3. Read about PEP-8 coding style and give better names to variables. For example, it is not easy to understand what does `fre` means in your code. But if you name it as `frequency`, the code will become more readable, and it will be easier to work with it.
4. to be continued

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. It finds `word` in `file` and counts how many times it is found in `words`:

```
file = open('hello.txt','r')
word = 'Python'
words = 0
for line in file:
  for word in line:
    words += 1
print('File contains ' + word + ' ' + str(words) + ' times' )
```

Comment: Note that if some lines contain the word more than one time, this code will not count all occurrences of the word in a sentence but only a number of lines where the word is present.

Comment: I would have love to use this script, but I am not searching one word, but many words entered by the user. I want to split the words and show that how many times they are repeating.